# Inherit xml documentation on overloaded functions in typescript

Tags: inheritance, typescript, xml-documentation

Is there some way for an overloaded function to inherit the same xml documentation as its base class?

[image]

[image] Hovering over myFunc

[image]
Hovering over myFunc, I would like to see the base class documentation and not just `(): void`.

Is this possible or do I have to write it separately in the sub-class?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation will show whenever you are dealing with a `Base` type, and that includes the following:

```
var klas: Base = new Klas();
```

You will get the documentation in this instance.

If you want the documentation when you are using `Klas` with its own type, add the following comment to your class...

```
/**
 * @constructor
 * @augments Base
 */
public class Klas {...
```

This will pull the documentation from `Base` into the `Klas` type. This is much easier than copying all of the individual documentation.

Comment: First part worked fine but it was the second part that I was looking for. However, it doesn't work... Anything else needed that I am missing?

Comment: It may be that your IDE doesn't honour it. You can see it working here: http://bit.ly/1oBima7

Comment: In your example the Sub doesn't have an overload implementation. Is there a way to get the base documentation for an overload function as well?

Comment: When you override a method, you need to provide new documentation, presumably because you must describe why it is different to the base implementation.

Comment: Right, but I have a scenario where I want the overloaded function to have the base documentation. This is not possible? I have to write it again in the overloaded function?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to get the docs in that case. `@augments` or `@extends` copies docs for everything inherited, but overridden members get the documentation removed.

Comment: Ok, so i guess the answer is no then. Thank you for trying!

Comment: @SteveFenton `@augments` or `@extends` not required for TypeScript (and actually have no effect in official tools)

Comment: It depends on IDE rather than language and affects the information shown alongside auto-completion hints.